# google-visualization Class ChartOptions get-method

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Refering to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-options it is possible to use the method `get(option)` for an `Class ChartOptions` object.

Using this code:

```
var allChartOptions = gcharts_LineChart.getOptions();
console.log(allChartOptions);
```

I get the log:

```
Object { title: "average", width: 1200, height: 500, LineSliceText: "value", legend: "bottom", trendlines: 0 }
```

Now to my problem: Unfortunately I can't use the `get(option)` method:

Code:

```
var allChartOptions = gcharts_LineChart.getOptions();
console.log(allChartOptions.get('title'));
```

Output:

```
TypeError: allChartOptions.get is not a function
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears `getOptions()` returns an object,
with properties you can access directly...

```
var allChartOptions = gcharts_LineChart.getOptions();
console.log(allChartOptions.title);
```

Comment: Oh sorry - I forgot it!